# how to pass shell variable to jq filter

Tags: shell, variables, jq

I try to pass a shell variable in that way:

```
jq -r --arg NEWGROUP "$NEWGROUP" '.[] | select(.name | contains("$NEWGROUP") ) | .id'
```

but it does not work.

when I specify the group name explicitly in the contains() it works.
am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> am I doing something wrong?

Yes, within the jq program, you have quoted what you intended to be the jq variable, thus turning it into a JSON string. Simply remove the quotation marks to let the $-string be the $-variable.

p.s. You probably should avoid `contains`, which has weird semantics. Depending on your jq, alternatives to consider include `index` and `test`.